# How can I draw diamonds in R with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate the following picture in R, in particular with `ggplot2`

[image]

I was able to draw the red rss contour lines but I've no idea how to draw a diamond (like the one in the left picture). The "expected Output" should be a way to draw a diamond with a given side length.

**EDIT:** Here is a short reproducible example to add the diamond randomly inside the following plot:

```
mlb<- read.table('https://umich.instructure.com/files/330381/download?download_frd=1', as.is=T, header=T)
str(mlb)

fit<-lm(Height~Weight+Age-1, data = as.data.frame(scale(mlb[,4:6])))
points = data.frame(x=c(0,fit$coefficients[1]),y=c(0,fit$coefficients[2]),z=c("(0,0)","OLS Coef"))

Y=scale(mlb$Height)
X = scale(mlb[,c(5,6)])
beta1=seq(-0.556, 1.556, length.out = 100)
beta2=seq(-0.661, 0.3386, length.out = 100)
df <- expand.grid(beta1 = beta1, beta2 = beta2)

b = as.matrix(df)
df$sse <- rep(t(Y)%*%Y,100*100) - 2*b%*%t(X)%*%Y + diag(b%*%t(X)%*%X%*%t(b))

base <- ggplot() + 
  stat_contour(data=df, aes(beta1, beta2, z = sse),breaks = round(quantile(df$sse, seq(0, 0.2, 0.03)), 0), 
               size = 0.5,color="darkorchid2",alpha=0.8) +

  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.4,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.55,0.4))+
  geom_point(data = points,aes(x,y))+
  geom_text(data = points,aes(x,y,label=z),vjust = 2,size=3.5)    
  base
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can draw shapes with `geom_polygon`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 0, -1, 0), y = c(0, 1, 0, -1))
ggplot(df) + geom_polygon(aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]

If you want to generate the coordinates from a center and a side length, you can transform a base matrix. You can also combine this with an existing plot by supplying the coordinates to the data argument of the `geom` instead of to `ggplot()` as shown. Change the sqrt2 scaling if you want the corner-to-center as the argument instead of the side length.

```r
diamond <- function(side_length, center) {
  base <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1), nrow = 2) * sqrt(2) / 2
  trans <- (base * side_length) + center
  as.data.frame(t(trans))
}

ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = diamond(2, c(1, 2)), mapping = aes(x = V1, y = V2))
```

[image]

Here's an example of adding it in to your provided data. Note that I put it before (underneath) the text, and named the arguments to be clear (probably the source of that `object coercible by fortify` error.

```r
mlb <- read.table("https://umich.instructure.com/files/330381/download?download_frd=1", as.is = T, header = T)

fit <- lm(Height ~ Weight + Age - 1, data = as.data.frame(scale(mlb[, 4:6])))
points <- data.frame(x = c(0, fit$coefficients[1]), y = c(0, fit$coefficients[2]), z = c("(0,0)", "OLS Coef"))

Y <- scale(mlb$Height)
X <- scale(mlb[, c(5, 6)])
beta1 <- seq(-0.556, 1.556, length.out = 100)
beta2 <- seq(-0.661, 0.3386, length.out = 100)
df <- expand.grid(beta1 = beta1, beta2 = beta2)

b <- as.matrix(df)
df$sse <- rep(t(Y) %*% Y, 100 * 100) - 2 * b %*% t(X) %*% Y + diag(b %*% t(X) %*% X %*% t(b))

ggplot(df) +
  stat_contour(aes(beta1, beta2, z = sse),
               breaks = round(quantile(df$sse, seq(0, 0.2, 0.03)), 0),
               size = 0.5, color = "darkorchid2", alpha = 0.8
  ) +
  geom_polygon(data = diamond(0.1, c(0, 0)), mapping = aes(x = V1, y = V2), fill = "cadetblue1") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.4, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.55, 0.4)) +
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(data = points, aes(x, y, label = z), vjust = 2, size = 3.5)
#> Warning: Removed 4215 rows containing non-finite values (stat_contour).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks that worked as a new plot, but cant combine it to my other one. I dont know if I can supply two different data frames inside one plot. I'll edit my post

Comment: You can add the coordinates to the data argument of the `geom`, instead of the `ggplot` call, so you can plot this on top of any other plot.

Comment: getting the error: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument? if I let the ggplot() empty and passind the data to geom

Comment: try explicitly naming the arguments `data` and `mapping`, I think I put them in the other order to how geom_polygon wants them

Comment: Works perfectly ! Just a last question for interest, why did you divide sqrt(2) / 2

Comment: the diamond with coordinates at (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1) has side length sqrt 2. (so I guess I did it wrong in my head and it should be divide by sqrt(2))